# How to group files into seperate folders by date modified?

Tags: linux, file-management, ext4

I have a large quantity of files that I would like to group into folders by year, using date modified, for convince. I am using an ext4 filesystem on linux. Are there any scripts/tools that could help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone stumbling across this in the future. I wrote this quick go program to do this. Pretty quick and dirty so don't expect it to be the most robust, but got the job done for me. It is not recursive, but to change that I think all you would have to do is remove the:

```go
if strings.Contains(path, "/") {
    return nil
}
```

```go
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main()  {
    directory := flag.String("directory", ".", "The directory to run in.")
    flag.Parse()

    if err := filepath.Walk(*directory, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if info.IsDir() {
                return nil
            }

            if strings.Contains(path, "/") {
                return nil
            }

            modified := info.ModTime()

            yearDirPath := strconv.Itoa(modified.Year())
            _ = os.Mkdir(yearDirPath, os.ModePerm)

            newPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", yearDirPath, path)
            if err := os.Rename(path, newPath); err != nil {
                return err
            }

            fmt.Printf("moved %s -> %s\n", path, newPath)

            return nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```